# VR viewer in matlab is not getting installed

Tags: matlab

the following is the error when i tried to install the VRviewer in matlab

```
>> vrinstall -install viewer
Installing blaxxun Contact viewer ...
Do you want to use OpenGL or Direct3D acceleration? (o/d) d
Starting viewer installation ...
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
Done.
```

Can anyone tell me why is the error coming??
and any alternatives to inbuilt viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-34E5AH/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-34E5AH

Alternatively, looks like a problem with spaces in directory names.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my problem the installation doesnt start so i think i need to search more on the error. will let you know if i find something

Comment: [link](http://help.wugnet.com/windows2/Program-space-batch-file-ftopict489742.html). the problem is due to the space in the name of my folder 'program files'. now my operating system is windows 7 and it some how is the root directory in my c drive where all the files are automatically installed. do you think it would cause a problem if i remove the space and put in an 'underscore'